# Jax-rs: consuming JSON and printing json on console

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have the following code working on my local eclipse setup which is accepting a JSON and printing it on the console using this 
`System.out.println(person);`

Since, there is `toString` method in the `Person.java` class, in order to see the output, I have to pass the JSON in the 
following manner via POSTMAN

`{"name":"Mickey","surname":"Mouse"}`

This will print the following on the console:

`16:05:16,409 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) Person [name=Mickey, surname=Mouse]`

**MyQuestion:**

If I have to accept a valid JSON like the following:

```
[{
    "name": "FirstName",
    "value": "Mickey"
}, {
    "name": "LastName",
    "value": "Mouse"
}]
```

Is it possible to use something else than the `toString` method in the `Person.java` class which will print the above JSON on the console?

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
package com.thejavageek.jaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

}
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
package com.mypackage.jaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import com.mypackage.jaxrs.model.Person;

    @Path("/HelloWorld")
    public class HelloWorldService {

        @POST
        @Path("/writePersonToDB")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void writePersonToDB(Person person) {

            System.out.println(person);

        }

    }
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.mypackage.jaxrs.model;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the following code working on my local eclipse setup which is
>   accepting a JSON and printing it on the console using this
>   System.out.println(person); --

If I am not mistaken, by the time you get to this line `System.out.println(person);` that JSON is being converted to Java object. And all Java objects have a `toString()` method, which is invoked when you try and, in your case, print the object in console.

> Is it possible to use something else than the toString method in the
>   Person.java class which will print the above JSON on the console?

`toString()` is just one way for an object to be converted to a string. But I suggest you not to rush looking for other solutions, but you can simply override it this way:

```
public String toString() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Person:\n");
     sb.append("name: ").append(this.getName()).append("\n")
        append("surname: ").append(this.getSurname()).append("\n");
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Or if you want this exactly like you state

> [{
>       "name": "FirstName",
>       "value": "Mickey" }, {
>       "name": "LastName",
>       "value": "Mouse" }]

You can always modify `toString()` method with the use of a `StringBuilder` object accordingly.

Please, try and maybe you will be happier with the outcome.

If that does not satisfy you, then you can look into Jackson's pretty-printing. For that simply check other threads on stackOverflow and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Although I had to add lot of `appends` for quotes, comma to make it  a valid json, this was much simpler than other solutions I believe. Thanks

Comment: @Coder, glad I could help !

Answer (score 1):

As always, Mkyong has the answer. Check out his post [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-jackson/).

In a nutshell, you need to serialize your Java object into a String. The framework will let you do it in XML or JSON (which is what you are looking for). You use Jackson for pretty-printing.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(person));
```

NB: other posts refer to GSON which is another library for JSON in Java.

Answer (score 0):

First: your method `public void writePersonToDB(Person person)` will not take input as you defined

```
[{
   "name": "FirstName",
   "value": "Mickey"
  }, {
   "name": "LastName",
   "value": "Mouse"
 }]
```

it is an Array or List, so you have to have a method which accepts `Array` or better a `List<Person>` as input

Second: what prevents you to create a method which will print your input (whatever it is - `Person` or `List<Person>`) in format you need? If you'd like print in JSON format use @david-brossard answer to do that. If you'd like another format as you have in `Person.toString()` build your own... all is up to you.